# Replace attribute on xml via command line

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I was looking this question [xmlstarlet update an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837879/xmlstarlet-update-an-attribute) and trying to replace an attribute inside a Jboss configuration file. 
I post here just a little part of the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:10.0">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    </extensions>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    </system-properties>
</server>
```

What i would like to replace is the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` from `validate` to **update**

Following the previous answer i tried this command, but dont update the value:

```
xmlstarlet edit   --update "//property[@name='hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto']/@value"   --value "update" conf.xml
```

I tried to follow the full path, but the result is the same: no update.

```
xmlstarlet edit   --update "/server/system-properties/property[@name='hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto']/@value"   --value "update" conf.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file uses [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128389/3776858) (`xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:10.0"`).

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//*[local-name()="property"][@name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"]/@value' -v "update" conf.xml
```

I used `//*[local-name()="property"]` to bypass all namespaces in conf.xml

Answer (score 2):

In Saxon 10.0's Gizmo utility (which aims to serve similar purposes to xmlstarlet) I decided to make unprefixed names match any namespace (or none). So the equivalent would be

```
java net.sf.saxon.Gizmo -s:conf.xml
/>update //property[@name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"]/@value with "update"
/>save conf.xml
/>quit
```

After years of seeing people struggling with namespaces, I'm coming to the view that having unprefixed names match any namespace is much more user-friendly.

Comment: That's an awesome idea!  You're right, there are so many questions on SO from people stuck by namespaces.  Wish this was the default behavior for XPath / XSL